# Calculate Chinese Year with MySql

Tags: mysql

Strange one. Trying to calculate the Chinese zodiac year in MySQL.  The years such as the year of the rat, tiger etc.  They go in intervals of 12 years so I suppose I need to mod it?

Any good suggestions for a nice and clean query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
SELECT
    (
        CASE
            WHEN MOD(a.year, 12) = 0 THEN 'Monkey'
            WHEN MOD(a.year, 12) = 1 THEN 'Rooster'
            WHEN MOD(a.year, 12) = 2 THEN 'Dog'
            WHEN MOD(a.year, 12) = 3 THEN 'Pig'
            WHEN MOD(a.year, 12) = 4 THEN 'Rat'
            WHEN MOD(a.year, 12) = 5 THEN 'Ox'
            WHEN MOD(a.year, 12) = 6 THEN 'Tiger'
            WHEN MOD(a.year, 12) = 7 THEN 'Hare'
            WHEN MOD(a.year, 12) = 8 THEN 'Dragon'
            WHEN MOD(a.year, 12) = 9 THEN 'Snake'
            WHEN MOD(a.year, 12) = 10 THEN 'Horse'
            WHEN MOD(a.year, 12) = 11 THEN 'Sheep'
        END
    ) AS ZodiacYear
FROM
    table a
```

Answer (score 1):

Or, if using single Chinese character, you can

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('鼠牛虎兔龙蛇马羊候鸡狗猪', (YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)-4)%12+1, 1);
```

**Note**

Chinese year use lunar calender, there're several months difference between lunar calendar and gregorian calendar.